# View traffic flowing through NAT machine

Tags: linux, networking, nat, cluster

I have been put in charge of an HPC cluster recently and the last admin didn't do a great job of documenting everything. We got a notification from our IT Security team that our head node has been accessing a sketchy freeware site on a pretty regular basis and we should check that out. Our head node is a NAT for the rest of the cluster so my assumption is the traffic isn't actually coming from the head node but is coming from some other machine that's talking through our head node. I've been running tcpdump -vvvv -A 'host [headnode ext IP]' on our head node for a while now to catch packets going to and from the freeware site, but that doesn't tell me which machine is actually making these requests. Can anyone give me a command to run (or likely a tcpdump flag that I'm missing) that will tell me the actual host that's making requests to this site?

Comment: Run the tcpdump on the inside interface. And you should not be using NAT if possible. Work with your networking people get rid of the NAT and just use normal campus-routable IPv4 and IPv6 addresses (and firewall them off if appropriate).

Comment: @MichaelHampton - If I'm not mistaken, Isn't NAT inevitable if infrastructure is running `6to4` on their edge, or if @Nick is running the HPC cluster an an RFC1918 subnet?

Comment: @ServerFault Sure, some universities are large enough that they actually need more IPv4 space than the /8 that network 10 provides. But this is very rare; most places are just throwing NAT all over the place because they don't know any better, or because campus IT intentionally makes departments' life difficult instead of working with them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would presume you have an external interface (perhaps `eth0`) which is doing NAT for machines on your internal interface (perhaps `eth1` with an RFC1918 subnet).  I would try running the cap on `eth1` to see which backend IP is accessing 104.25.236.8. eg: `tcpdump -i eth1 -vvvv -A src 104.25.236.8 or dst 104.25.236.8`